# open a textfile and remove redundant lines and characters

Tags: python, text-files

I have a textfile containing words, characters, numbers, and empty lines  as below:

```
This is an example /
The Date is: 07 Feb 2022
2.03 4.0 5.0 2*6 3*4
9e-2 7.0 2 6 2*3 5.0 /
```

I want to only keep those lines with numbers, and delete `/` anywhere in the file. Also I want to change those numbers next to the `*` in such a way that:

`2*6` becomes `6 6`

`3*4` becomes `4 4 4`

`2*3` becomes `3 3`

And finally have such a file

```
2.03 4.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
9e-2 7.0 2.0 6.0 3.0 3.0 5.0
```

I have written a code to do these, but the run time is high and I think it is not a good way to do that.

I initially opened the textfile and removed the `/` and saved that file as `target1`

```
import os
import time
start = time.time()

with open('Ptest1.txt, 'r') as infile1, open('target1.txt', 'w') as outfile1:
    A = infile1.read()
    B = A.replace("/", "")
    outfile1.write(B)
```

Then, I opened it again and this time I removed the lines holding letters and empty lines using this code, and saved it as `target2`:

```
keep_these = []
def is_valid(t):
    try:
        float(t.replace('*', '0'))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return False

with open('target1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as infile2, open('target2.txt', 'w') as outfile2:
    for line in infile2:
        if all(is_valid(t) for t in line.strip().split()):
            keep_these.append(line)
            if line.strip():
                outfile2.write(line)

os.remove('target1.txt')
```

Finally, I used this code below to expand the numbers at the sides of `*`

```
T = open('target2.txt', 'r')

def expand(a):
    import numpy as np
    b = a.readlines()
    c = [x.replace('\n','') for x in b]
    d = [j for i in c for j in i.split()]
    e=[]
    for i in d:
        if "*" in i:
            a=[i.split("*")[1]]*int(i.split("*")[0])
            e.extend(a)
        else:
            e.append(i)
    f = np.array(e)
    g = [float(numeric_string) for numeric_string in f]
    h = np.array(g)
    return h

MM = expand(T)

end = time.time()
print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
```

Comment: One thing, e is technically a letter, should we ignore lines with only e in them?

Comment: yes, you are right. But, I want to keep those lines with e as well.

Comment: How long does execution take when you run this on the example?

Comment: This is just an example of my textfile. My textfile is very big. It has around 400,000 lines and after expanding it becomes around 28 milion single numbers. The whole process takes around 25 seconds.

Comment: Is it possible to paste a larger sample (maybe have a few thousand lines on pastebin or similar)? I would just like to test my own solution against yours to see if there is a difference before posting.

Comment: Can you see the file through this link?
https://www.mediafire.com/file/szo2h8pe0apfzl2/Test.txt/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried:

```
import os
import time
import string

start = time.time()
def expand(chunk):

    l = chunk.split("*")
    chunk = [str(float(l[1]))] * int(l[0])

    return chunk

with open('/path/to/Test.txt', 'r') as infile1, open('target1.txt', 'w') as outfile1:
    for line in infile1:
        if set(string.ascii_letters.replace("e","")) & set(line):
            continue

        chunks = line.split(" ")
        #Get rid of newlines
        chunks = list(map(lambda chunk: chunk.strip(), chunks))
        if "/" in chunks:
            chunks.remove("/")

        new_chunks = []
        for i in range(len(chunks)):
            if '*' in chunks[i]:
                new_chunks += expand(chunks[i])
            else:
                new_chunks.append(chunks[i])
        new_chunks[len(new_chunks)-1] = new_chunks[len(new_chunks)-1]+"\n"
        new_line = " ".join(new_chunks)
        outfile1.write(new_line)

end = time.time()
print(f"Runtime of the program is {end - start}")
```

I timed both your program and my program using the text file provided in the comments and I got:

```
Runtime of the program is 1.3493189811706543
```

for mine and

```
Runtime of the program is 4.36532998085022
```

for yours. Checking the differences, there are about four more lines out of some 71k lines produced by my code in comparison to your code, so I think the results do not deviate too much.

One issue I noticed is that the results of MM are not written to the file at the end. Anyways, let me know if this code above leads to faster processing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. Your code reduces the time from 25 sec to around 5 seconds for my full dataset. Just I got a little bit confused with the code. If I want to get the number of final elements after expanding, what variable should I pick?

Comment: @PeymanBahrami May you clarify what you mean by number of final elements? Like on a line or in the entire file?

Comment: I want to check your code to see if the final number of elements is the same as mine? 
in my code when I get the shape of MM it is 3402000. I wondered to know what is yours?

Comment: @PeymanBahrami I think the final number of lines differs minimally. I will check through myself tomorrow and include a count

Comment: actually not the number of lines. 3402000 is the number of single values (floats)

Comment: I checked that again. It works well and gives the same number of floats. But, I opened the saved text file (target1) as:
f = open('target1.txt').read();
A = f.split();
B = list(map(float, A));
print(len(B));

and I will get 3402000. I am wondered to know what parameter should I pick in your code and get its length to see the same length.

Comment: @PeymanBahrami I believe your way of extracting this is good, I would use this. I did not track the counts in the code I put up because I did not see this mentioned in the original question. Using len(B) will be fine.